# create a notification bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im able to print a message at the top, but the css doesnt work as supposed.
I want it to look like this and be placed at the bottom:

[image]

Also, it is an error message i want the color to be red and displaying for 4000 ms, else if it is success i want it to be green and displaying for 1000ms.
If the notification bar already is showing i want to switch the notification bar to the new one.

The code so far:

```js
function error(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('#notify-error').html(msg).slideDown();
}

function success(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('#notify-success').html(msg).slideDown();
}


    $('#notify-error').click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp().empty();
    });

    $('#notify-success').click(function () {
        $(this).slideUp().empty();
    });

error('Error!');
success('Success!');
```

```css
/* css: */

     #notify-success {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background-color:green;
        height:30px;
        color:white;
        display:none;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        font-size:2em;
        line-height:1em;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border:2px solid #666;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    
     #notify-error {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background-color:red;
        height:30px;
        color:white;
        display:none;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        font-size:2em;
        line-height:1em;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border:2px solid #666;
        cursor:pointer;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xP37L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i had made some changes in your `JS` and `CSS`.

in your js you are adding a class with `#` such as `addClass('#notify-error')` Which denotes the id so i have remove it from JS functions `error(msg)` and `success(msg)`

```js
/* JS */

    function error(msg) {
        $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown();
    }
    
    function success(msg) {
        $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-success').html(msg).slideDown();
    }
    
    
        $('#notify-error').click(function () {
            $(this).slideUp().empty();
        });
    
        $('#notify-success').click(function () {
            $(this).slideUp().empty();
        });
    
    
    error('Error!');
    success('Success!');
```

```css
/* CSS */

    .notify-success {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background-color:green;
        height:30px;
        color:white;
        display:none;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        font-size:2em;
        line-height:1em;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border:2px solid #666;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    
     .notify-error {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        background-color:red;
        height:30px;
        color:white;
        display:none;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        font-size:2em;
        line-height:1em;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border:2px solid #666;
        cursor:pointer;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

see your [**UPDATE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xP37L/2/)

Comment: Thank you! :) I want the notification bar to appear in the bottom and if it is an error message i want it to display for 4000 ms, else if it is success i want it to display for 1000ms. And If the notification bar already is showing i want to be replaced with the new one. How can i achieve this?

Comment: you can simply pass the 4000 or 1000 to your `slideDown()` function as `slideDown(4000)` or `slideDown(1000)`see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xP37L/10/

Comment: Thank you. I solved it by: function error(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown(500).delay(4000).slideUp(500);
} but now the last problem, i want it to appearing at the bottom at the page and not at the top?

function success(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-success').html(msg).slideDown(500).slideUp(500);
}

Comment: ya that is in the fiddle also.

Comment: Still appearing in the top and not at the bottom of the page. :(

Comment: now all is CSS game add css `position:fixed` and `bottom:0px` see again the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xP37L/11/   i had put `success` in bottom

Answer (score 1):

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) adds a **class** to the element so you have to change your *CSS selector*:

Change **CSS**:

```
#notify-success{...} -> .notify-success{...}
#notify-error{...} -> .notify-error{...}
```

And **JS**:

```
.addClass('#notify-success') -> .addClass('notify-success')
.addClass('#notify-error') -> .addClass('notify-error')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xP37L/3/)

Comment: Thank you! :) I want the notification bar to appear in the bottom and if it is an error message i want it to display for 4000 ms, else if it is success i want it to display for 1000ms. And If the notification bar already is showing i want to be replaced with the new one. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove from the addclass the "#" char.

```
function error(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown();
}

function success(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-success').html(msg).slideDown();
}
```

Also in the css change this

```
#notify-error and  #notify-success
```

to this

```
.notify-error and  .notify-success
```

UPDATE:

you can achieve the second part by fixing this part of the code:

```
function error(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown(4000);
    $('.notify-success').hide();
}

function success(msg) {
    $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-success').html(msg).slideDown(1000);
    $('.notify-error').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I want the notification bar to appear in the bottom and if it is an error message i want it to display for 4000 ms, else if it is success i want it to display for 1000ms. And If the notification bar already is showing i want to be replaced with the new one. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add style to id thats the problem

Try this :

```js
/* JS */
        function error(msg) {
         $('<div>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown();
          }

             function success(msg) {
            $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-success').html(msg).slideDown();
         }


         $('body').on('click','.notify-error',function () {
              $(this).slideUp().empty();
          });

           $('body').on('click','.notify-success',function () {
             $(this).slideUp().empty();
          });


        error('Error!');
        success('Success!');
```

```css
/* CSS */

    .notify-success {
      position:relative;
   width:100%;
   background-color:green;
   height:30px;
   color:white;
   display:none;
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px;
   font-size:2em;
   line-height:1em;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   border:2px solid #666;
   cursor:pointer;
  }

  .notify-error {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   background-color:red;
   height:30px;
   color:white;
   display:none;
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px;
   font-size:2em;
   line-height:1em;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   border:2px solid #666;
   cursor:pointer;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I want the notification bar to appear in the bottom and if it is an error message i want it to display for 4000 ms, else if it is success i want it to display for 1000ms. And If the notification bar already is showing i want to be replaced with the new one. How can i achieve this?

Comment: `function error(msg) {
     $('<div>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown().slideUp(1000);
      }

         function success(msg) {
        $('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-success').html(msg).slideDown().slideUp(4000);
     }`

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding class attribute in this line `$('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('#notify-error').html(msg).slideDown();` You should not write '#'. It should be like this `$('<div/>').prependTo('body').addClass('notify-error').html(msg).slideDown();` after this change your CSS from `#notift-error` to `.notify-error`  same for the notify-success. In HTML are just declaring attributes and their value the selector '#' for ID and '.' for class is used for while selecting them in CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! :) I want the notification bar to appear in the bottom and if it is an error message i want it to display for 4000 ms, else if it is success i want it to display for 1000ms. And If the notification bar already is showing i want to be replaced with the new one. How can i achieve this?